# Mongo Sort Aggregation not working on Sub Document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Trying to sort the sub-key on the document.

Example of data from the pipeline. Incorrect sort order for subkey `availability.startIso`

```
{
            "_id": "60e458d7b896de9c8e44d6c9",
            "uid": "6233ed1d8b154aa79d1435b5",
            "name": "Pale",
            "phoneNumber": "+19999813917",
            "profileMedia": {
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/refresh-me-dev.appspot.com/dummy_photos/dummy_1.jpg",
                "type": "photo"
            },
            "createdIso": "2021-07-06T13:21:27.513Z",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "isFlagged": false,
            "isBanned": false,
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isVendor": true,
            "lastOpenedAppIso": "2021-07-06T13:21:27.513Z",
            "vendorMeta": {
                "servicesOffered": [
                    "swedish"
                ],
                "location": [
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "distanceFromPoint": 0,
            "availability": [
                {
                    "_id": "60e458d7b896de9c8e44d6cc",
                    "uid": "dec97d4b1dea44f7b2fa45a5",
                    "vendorUid": "6233ed1d8b154aa79d1435b5",
                    "startIso": "2021-07-12T04:07:21.349Z",
                    "endIso": "2021-07-12T05:07:21.360Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60e458d7b896de9c8e44d6ce",
                    "uid": "a5928ea5c18c4321bd6a9a9b",
                    "vendorUid": "6233ed1d8b154aa79d1435b5",
                    "startIso": "2021-07-11T01:52:18.323Z",
                    "endIso": "2021-07-11T02:52:18.335Z"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Example of the aggregation

```
let vendors = await mongoDb
        .collection<User>(collectionNames.users)
        .aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat, lng] },
                    spherical: true,
                    maxDistance: 7500,
                    distanceField: "distanceFromPoint",
                },
            },
            {
                $match: { isVendor: true },
            },
            {
                $match: { "vendorMeta.servicesOffered": { $in: services } },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "vendor.availability",
                    localField: "uid",
                    foreignField: "vendorUid",
                    as: "availability",
                },
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    availability: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$availability",
                            as: "availability",
                            cond: { $and: [{ $gte: ["$$availability.startIso", nowIso] }, { $lte: ["$$availability.endIso", nDaysIso] }] },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            { $sort: { "availability.startIso": 1 } },
            { $match: { availability: { $ne: [] } } },
        ])
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended, `$sort` does not work on arrays and can't be used like this. What you can do is `$unwind`, then `$sort` and end by `$group`ing to restore the structure, like so:

```
[
    // ...,
    {
        $unwind: "$availability"
    },
    { $sort: { "availability.startIso": 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            root: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
            availability: {$push: '$availability'}
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    '$root',
                    { availability: '$availability'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Note that i removed the :

```
{ $match: { availability: { $ne: [] } } },
```

As it's no longer required because `$unwind` will remove those documents for you.

Comment: Thanks works perfect; ```{ $match: { availability: { $ne: [] } } },``` also removes the vendors with no availability. :-)